# Cauchy Principal Value for log integral

Tags: logarithms, cauchy-principal-value

How do I evaluate the expression

$\lim_{\xi\to0}(\int_0^\xi\! \ln(\frac{1}{r})\frac{F}{\xi} \, \mathrm{d}r) $ , where$\ F,\xi $ are real numbers and  $\xi\geq0$.

Integration gives the expression

$\lim_{\xi\to0}[\frac{F}{\xi}(r\ln(\frac{1}{r}) + r)] $ where $r$ is evaluated at $\ 0 $ and $\xi$.

The first term is singular and be can't be evaluated. Can this integral be defined in a Cauchy Principal Value sense, or evaluated in another way to remove the singularity?

Thanks

Comment: Oops, didn't see you've edited your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral itself need not be evaluated as a PV because

$$
\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^+} r \ln \frac{1}{r} = 0
$$

So you have

$$
\lim_{\xi\rightarrow0} \frac{F}{\xi} \left( \xi \ln \frac{1}{\xi} + \xi - 0 \right) \\
= F \lim_{\xi\rightarrow0} \left( \ln \frac{1}{\xi} + 1 \right) \\
$$

which does not exist.

Comment: This is my problem. I need a way to remove the singularity or define the integration differently so I can evaluate the expression.

Comment: @GradyF.MathewsIv In some circumstances, people do a Hadamard "finite-part" regularization of integrals that don't quite exist even as a PV. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization.  It essentially involves "throwing away an infinity".